# ubuntu 22 LTS adduser not copying /etc/skel

Tags: adduser

I've added users to 4 nodes of a microk8s cluster using

useradd user

and typing password and hitting enter to all the asked for info...  from what I have read this should copy the contents of the /etc/skel folder to the users homedir?  it does not.  Not a huge deal, I can fix it, but just wondering why I am reading that it should and it doesn't.
thanks
Bill

Comment: Your title mentions `adduser`, but the body of your question says that you used `useradd` - these are different commands. In particular, `useradd` does not create the user's home directory unless given the `-m` option - so there's nowhere to copy the skeleton files to.

Comment: sorry, doing too many things at once, I used adduser and it does not copy the skel folder.